# Are there any public APIs for ENS lookup?

Tags: ens, external-api

I want to add ENS support to an app I am building, and I am looking for a lightweight API which supports ENS to Ethereum address conversion.

All the documentation shows how you can do this on the blockchain, and it appears like Web3.js will work, but I am wondering if there is anything more lightweight than this, like a public GET API which returns JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no API to have a ENS lookup, the only way you can get the address from ENS is calling the ENS contract.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum blockchain is accessed by JSON-RPC API that uses HTTP GET/POST as its transport.

To get a Ethereum JSON-RPC API node see https://ethereumnodes.com/

For example, Cloudflare offers a free API servers.

Then you can use a Web3.js/Ether.hs and ENS ABI files to call the smart contract to fetch the information. If you want to get more lightweight you can construct the same JSON-RPC HTTP calls by hand, but it is an unreadable mess and advised against, so don't do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can register an API key at https://etherscan.io/apis and call their JSON API. I think if you experiment a bit by calling the name service contract, you should be able to extract this information.

Specifically you can call the `contract` module via the `getabi` method, passing the contract address.

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?\
module=account&\
action=balance&\
address=<your contract address>&\
tag=latest&\
apikey=<your API key>
```

You can simply use the ENS name instead of the address. This also works with the `account` module.

Comment: I must be blind. Where is the ens api mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: If you like the answer, upvote it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't like the answer because I do not see evidence of an API at etherscan

Comment: Hmmm, I included the link... Tell me how you want me to improve the answer rather than down-voting.

Comment: I did not down vote you. Others did for the same reason I did not accept your answer. Etherscan.io does not appear to expose a public API which resolves ens names. Show me where it does, and the documents in for it, and I will be happy to give you a positive vote.

Comment: Using the ENS name doesn't appear to work now:
`$ for name in 0xf4F7F1BD0905EFe61382dE895eC3C1eD321B995b martindengler.eth ; do echo "${name}: $(curl --silent --show-error "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=${name}&tag=latest&apikey=Q5JXF4A6ATY5G8PBTWW8SHF8N955J1SQXM")" ; done
0xf4F7F1BD0905EFe61382dE895eC3C1eD321B995b: {"status":"1","message":"OK","result":"116002963767805986"}
martindengler.eth: {"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Error! Invalid address format"}`